# Set encoding vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I created a CustomLayout but doesn't work encoding. Here in Brazil we use accentuation on some words but when I display my CustomLayout this words show < ? >.

Example: Nação(nation)-> displayed Na< ? >< ? >o.

How to set encoding in vaadin 7 ?

Comment: You've tried to do that?

String newString = new String(oldString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin uses UTF-8 so save your CustomLayout file in UTF-8 and it will work.

Comment: @FernandoPaiva In your editor/IDE define that you save your files in UTF-8. For example in Eclipse go to `Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Text file encoding`.

Comment: my eclipse is set with UTF-8 and in my TomCat6 that I use to test does work normal but when I create war file and deploy in other TomCat6(official) server that I use after finish the project doesn't work.